# PHP -> get random two random files from two different folders

Tags: php, arrays, image

So what i am trying to achieve is get two random image files that are going to be thumbnails of two different folder. These two images will be called using function randomThumbnail($dirs)
$dirs is an array containing two different folder location. Thanks in advance!
what am i doin wrong? iS THE QUESTION.

```
function randomThumbnail($albums_location){ #TODO: finish this function

 //$images = scandir($albums_location); old ver
 //$i = rand(2, sizeof($images)-1); old ver
$images = glob($albums_location . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];    
    return $randomImage;
}
```

sorry for not being clear.. im just goin to put the code clear for u guys then ill switch it all to classes

```
$y = $_GET['year'];  
$dir_photos = 'photos/'
$folders = scandir($dir_photos.$y);
foreach($folders as $albumFolder){
    if($albumFolder == '.' OR $albumFolder == '..'){
     $albumFolder = '';
    } else {
      $thumbnails = $this->randomThumbnail($dir_photos.$y.'/'.$albumFolder);
          echo '<img src="'.$thumbnails.'" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: what is $this->dir_photos,  what is $y and why are you using $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; $images is an array so you are putting a random array inside an array?

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: That code looks to be doing exactly that. What's the problem with it?

Comment: so call glob twice, once for each folder. merge the two arrays, then pull out your random value...

Comment: its not working at all.  i get  Undefined index error in the line where $randonImage.. i guess because the answer #1

Comment: is there a way to do this like this call images in one folder and get a random file, then call images in another folder and get a random file. then put those TWO files in one array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that the glob() function doesn't list the files correctly because the path isn't finishing by a slash.

Check the path carefully.

[EDIT]
Check this line:

```
$thumbnails = $this->randomThumbnail($dir_photos.$y.'/'.$albumFolder);
```

Make a var_dump before this line as :

```
var_dump($dir_photos.$y.'/'.$albumFolder);
```

Instead of :

```
$thumbnails = $this->randomThumbnail($dir_photos.$y.'/'.$albumFolder);
```

try:

```
$thumbnails = $this->randomThumbnail($dir_photos.$y.'/'.$albumFolder.'/');
```

Comment: i guess I was in the right direction all along. its just that i just switch from using  scandir() where u dont need a slash at the end of the path. Thank you all i was missing was a slash in the path.

Comment: If this solve your problem, please mark it as solved. Thank you.

Comment: mm exactly how do i do that. sorry new to this awesome sie

Comment: You must click on the checkbox sign on the left side of the answer.